# Knockout conditional binding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, single-page-application

Ok, I've been been building a SPA application, and looking to have a different layout depending on whether the site is viewed on a phone or laptop.

If using Bootstrap, it provides conditional hiding/showing of css classes, and while that works nicely for what it does, it doesn't work well when the layout changes beyond a certain point. with this alternative layout, I wind up needing to put two sets of divs on one page, then use some conditional Javascript code to wipe out the inner html of the target div. This prevents charts from being populated into parts of the page that will never be seen.

```
    var setViewscape = function () {
    var l = $(".positionDetails").length;
    if (l == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            setViewscape();
        }, 10);
    } else {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 899) {
            $(".landscape").html("");
            $(".phonescape").css("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
            $(".phonescape").html("");
            $(".landscape").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    }
};
```

So far so good, except when I observe what is happening on the page with Knockout, the second set of knockout tags are still being bound to. I tried adding a ko conditional to only bind to those controls I am intending to show:

```
<div id="content" class="main">
    <div class="row landscape">
        <!--ko if: $(window.innerWidth > 899) -->
        <div class="col-8 col-lg-8">
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'positions/list'} --><!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-4 " > 
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'shared/summaryGraph'} --><!--/ko-->
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'shared/memberSummary'} --><!--/ko-->
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'shared/memberCalendar'} --><!--/ko-->
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'shared/memberTwitter'} --><!--/ko-->
            <div data-bind="visible: advert() != null && advert().length > 0" id="advert"  class="img-rounded container-fluid" style="min-width: 120px; min-height: 680px; height: inherit; margin-bottom: 30px; background-color:whitesmoke ">
                <h4>Advert</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--/ko-->
    </div>
    <div  class="row phonescape" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 15px;">
    <!--ko if: $(window.innerWidth <= 899) -->
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'shared/memberSummary'} --><!--/ko-->
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'shared/sagaSummaryGraph'} --><!--/ko-->
            <!--ko compose: {view: 'positions/list'} --><!--/ko--> 
        </div>
    <!--/ko-->
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I observe the debug info I see
["Binding", "views/positions/list", ko.bindingContext]
["Binding", "views/positions/list", ko.bindingContext]

["Binding", "views/shared/memberSummary", ko.bindingContext]
["Binding", "views/shared/memberSummary", ko.bindingContext]

["Binding", "views/shared/summaryGraph", ko.bindingContext]
["Binding", "views/shared/summaryGraph", ko.bindingContext]

I am certain this has got to be a performance hit.

What I'm trying to do is to only bind to either the 'phonescape' or 'landscape' mode and remove what must certainly be a performance hit. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I used an observable extension to do something like this where the extension updates an observable based on whether a media query is hit or not.  You would define an observable like:

```
this.large = ko.observable().matchMedia("(min-width: 800px)");
```

Then, you can bind areas of your page against "large"  ( like `if: large`) to prevent areas from being bound that you don't want.

The code is a bit naive in that it only supports min/max width queries against px based measurements in older browsers.

Here is what I was using:

```
//small extension to update an observable based on a media query
(function() {
    var self = ko.observable.fn.matchMedia = function(query) {
        self["matchMedia" in window ? "syncWithMatchMedia" : "syncWithResize"](this, query);
        return this;
    };

    self.syncWithMatchMedia = function(observable, mediaQuery) {
        var query = window.matchMedia(mediaQuery);

        observable(query.matches);

        query.addListener(function(query) {
            observable(query.matches);
        });
    };

    self.syncWithResize = function(observable, mediaQuery) {
        var pieces = mediaQuery.split(":"),
            isMax = pieces[0].indexOf("max") > -1,
            value = pieces[1].replace(")", "").replace("px",""), //just works with px for now
            currentWidth;

        var matcher = function() {
            var width = document.outerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

            //see if something changed
            if (width !== currentWidth) {
                currentWidth = width;
                observable(isMax ? value > width : value < width);
            }
        }

        matcher();

        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(window, "resize", matcher);
    };
})();
```

It falls back to use a `resize` event, if the `matchMedia` API is not supported by the browser.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/7s2hZ/